# Accessing Remote Registry for the currently logged in user with Powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, registry, printers

I'm trying to find the printer ports that are in use for the user that is logged in to multiple machines. However, when I run my script it is running Regedit as myself... How do I go about getting it for the user that is logged in?

Here is my current script:

```
Get-Content -Path c:\ListOfComputers.txt | ForEach-Object {
Get-ItemProperty -Path Registry::"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\PrinterPorts\" | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath} | Format-List | Out-file c:\PortResults.txt
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Check if a Registry Path Exists in Remote Machine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10275133/check-if-a-registry-path-exists-in-remote-machine)

Comment: Not really the same thing. I'm only able to pull local data, but if I use a remote IP address it gives an error

Comment: You can't directly query HKCU on a remote machine. You can only access the hive if you find the user's SID, and access it in the HKEY_USERS key.

Comment: That is what I figured. I found this: http://powershell.com/cs/media/p/16643.aspx but it doesn't seem to work correctly...

Comment: I created a new Question here: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37793956/how-to-use-powershell-to-find-information-for-current-users-network-printers).